# Draw signature and upload via DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I have a question. Is there any possibility to draw a sign for document usign API? I have a webpage with canvas. Can i send the picture sign via API? C# for example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly what you want to do, so sorry if this is off base. You can send the data necessary to draw something. Basically, you can send a bunch of points which can be connected by lines or whatever. I would have to ask how are you storing the "sign" you want to draw? Sorry - I just noticed the tags. I'm pretty unfamiliar with those technologies other than C#.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And "check" the answer that best answers your own questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking:

Can I upload a person's graphical signature to DocuSign via the API?

The answer is yes. See the docs for [UserSignatures: create](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Users/UserSignatures/create/) method. This method is not included with the SDK, you will need to call it directly.

If, instead, you're asking:

With DocuSign, can my app *sign* a document by sending a graphical signature via the API?

The answer is No. Documents are signed by using the DocuSign Signing Ceremony either directly or by embedding the Signing Ceremony within your application. See the [embedded signing docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/embedded_signing.html).